# Can anyone share this colour pallet and set up for Git CLI?

Tags: git, terminal, console

I've seen this on a few people consoles now, how do I get my git repos to visually have emojis in them:
[image]

Edit: I have zsh set up, I was just looking for this particular style.

Comment: That's not a thing of your git repo. That's a shell thing. And this one is customized like "fast&furious"-level ... Maybe search for "shell ricing" or something like that. Or: ask one of "those people".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a shell profile, nothing to do with git. If your shell is zsh try [oh my zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes).

Answer (score 1):

I must install the *zsh plugin* on a console software (git bash, powershell...), then you will see it as in your posted picture.

Official documentation about [**zsh**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Zsh) from git.

[Tutorial](https://dev.to/zinox9/installing-zsh-on-windows-37em) for installing zsh-plugin